# What is the meaning of きたきがする in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

The sentence is:

俺もすこし分かってきたきがする、ま、勘違いなんだろうけど

I just need some help understanding how this sentence is structured and what 'kita ki ga suru' indicates over here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separation is incorrect. It should be:
分かってきた / きがする

分かってきた here it means “finally understand”.

きがする (usually written as 気がする) means “I think...” in this context.

So the sentence means “I think I finally understand a little bit, but I may have got it wrong though.”